# How am I meant to see the errors in this response return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() }); I just see a 400 bad request in my console

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to implement validation on my Node.js back-end so whenever the data doesn't pass the validation, I'm sending this to the front-end:

```
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
}
```

so that I could render the errors on the front-end. Sadly, when I open the console, I only see:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/login 400 (Bad Request)
```

as opposed to an object that would contain config, data, headers, request and status. So I am wondering how the hell am I supposed to access the errors object I'm returning to the front-end. I'm following express-validator's docs and this is how they do it as well - https://express-validator.github.io/docs/index.html

Comment: can you post full snippet?

Comment: if you are expecting that particular error on the frontend then you can simply catch that error and do whatever you need to do. otherwise if you want a custom error from the backend, you might need to pass status 200 but with a object/json containing the message.

Comment: What does your client-side code look like? How are you making the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to retrieve and parse the response body, even for non-successful requests.

Here's an example using `fetch` but the approach would be similar using other libs

```js
const doFetch = async (url) => {
  const res = await fetch(url, {
    // method, headers, body, etc
  })
  if (!res.ok) {
    if (res.status === 400) {
      throw await res.json() // this will parse the JSON response body
    }
    // handle other errors
    throw { errors: [ res.statusText ] } // conform to a standard format
  }
  // handle success
}

doFetch('http://example.com').catch(({ errors }) => {
  console.error(errors)
})
```